# How do I find the image of a point in a line in 3D space?

Tags: analytic-geometry, 3d

The question is,

> find the image of the point $(1, 6, 3)$ in the line $$\frac x1 = \frac {y-1}{2} = \frac {z-2}{3}$$

I want to know the general equation to find the image of a point in a line.

*EDIT*

By image, I mean a point which is diametrically opposite to the point, on the opposite side of the line

Comment: Do you mean the projection of this point onto the line?

Comment: no, I don't. I want to find the _image_ of the point, ie another point perpendicularly opposite and at the same distance to the line.

Comment: If you determine $\vec{w}$ as in my answer below, then the point opposite to $\vec{u}$ can be found with $\vec{w}-(\vec{u}-\vec{w}) = 2 \vec{w}-\vec{u}$

Comment: Thanks! it worked out correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $Q(a,b,c)$ be the image of $P(1,6,3)$ in the given line.Then direction ratios of $PQ$ are $(a-1,b-6,c-3)$
As the given line and $PQ$ will be perpendicular to each other.So $a_1a_2+b_1b_2+c_1c_2=0$ is the condition of perpendicularity
$1(a-1)+2(b-6)+3(c-3)=0$
$a+2b+3c=22..........(1)$
Now the mid point of $PQ(\frac{a+1}{2},\frac{b+6}{2},\frac{c+3}{2})$ will lie on the line.
Write the equation of line in parametric form
$x=t,y=2t+1,z=3t+2$

So $\frac{a+1}{2}=t,\frac{b+6}{2}=2t+1,\frac{c+3}{2}=3t+2$
$a=2t-1,b=4t-4,c=6t+1$
Put this in equation $(1)$,find $t$ and hence find $(a,b,c)$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: set $$x=t$$, $$\frac{y-1}{2}=t$$ and $$\frac{z-2}{3}=t$$ and you will get the equation of the line

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/549134)

Comment: yes i know this sentence. Do you got a new one?

Comment: Here's a new one: hint or otherwise, an answer is only good if the asker can see that it applies to the question asked. For example, you could make your post much better by adding the statement "solving for each variable in terms of $t$ gives you a parameterization of the line".

Answer (score 0):

Write everything in terms of z. $x=\frac{z-2}{3},y=\frac{2z-1}{3},z=z$. Then convert to vector form.
$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 x \\
 y \\
 z \\
\end{array}
\right)=z \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 \frac{1}{3} \\
 \frac{2}{3} \\
 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)+\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 -\frac{2}{3} \\
 -\frac{1}{3} \\
 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Consider this as the vector equation $\vec{x}=z\vec{v}+\vec{p}$.
Now project the point $\vec{u}=(1,6,3)$ onto this line with $\vec{w}=\frac{\vec{u}.\vec{v}}{\vec{v}.\vec{v}}\vec{v}$ giving $(1,3,5)$

[image: Projecting a point onto a line]

Answer (score 0):

To find the image of a point in a line, you must first find the equation of the normal to the line through the point.

Find $\vec m $ so that $\vec l . \vec m = 0$ where $\vec l$ is the vector of the line and $\vec m$ is the vector of the perpendicular through the point.

find the coords of the point of intersection of the two lines.

The image of a point from a line is the same distance from the line as the point itself. So, we can use the mid-point formula of a line segment, solving for $x', y',$ and $z'$ where $x', y',$ and $z'$ are coords of the image.